# How to update multiple rows at once using Django forms.ModelForm in views.py

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to update many rows of a model based on user input but I'm having trouble updating them in views.py.

I create the modelForm

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ["book_title", "book_title_2"]
```

In my views

```
def my_view(request):
    query = MyModel.objects.filter(foo=foo)
    forms = [MyForm(instance=q) for q in query]
    context["forms"] = forms
```

In templates I iterate over forms and input data for some rows. I know normally on form submission I can use `form = MyForm(request.POST)` and use the `is_valid()` and `save()` attributes to save new data to my model. But when I am using a list of forms like above to update many instances, how can I actually save the forms in views.py? When I call `MyForm(request.POST)` after submitting all of the queried forms at once I get this error `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'FORM'` . When I look at the post data I see a list values for `book_title` and `book_title_2`. It seems that because I'm submitting more than one form it doesn't work. Is there a workaround for this? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Answer (score 1):

As posted in the comments by Willem Formsets is exactly what is needed to handle multiple form in views. In my case specifically where I am making multiple forms based on a model and a queryset of that model, `modelformset_factory` worked

Comment: There is also a useful tutorial at: https://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html